# How to make an animation where hint text in textbox moves up to groupbox header in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to make an animation where the hint text in the textbox moves up towards the groupbox header using XAML and WPF.

A picture to illustrate:
[image]

Left is unfocused, Right is focused.

**UPDATE:**

I have some questions:

**1**. My problem is: when I write some text --> delete all text --> the hint text goes to deafult value of TranslateTransform and moves up again to 0, hint text sould stay up. (animation works when it sould not to).

**2**.My code is not dynamic for any textbox height (i dont know what calclulation to do).

**Code:**

```html
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StringEpmtyConverter x:Key="StringEpmtyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Groupbox_Temp" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" Header="" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Groupbox_To_Animate, Path=FontSize}">
            <GroupBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="GroupBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource StringEpmtyConverter}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </GroupBox.Style>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Groupbox_To_Animate" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="17">
            <GroupBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="GroupBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Hint" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <TranslateTransform Y="22"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="True"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource StringEpmtyConverter}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="True"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="focused"/>
                                                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="unfocused_empty"/>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="False"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="focused"/>
                                                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="unfocused_empty"/>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="unfocused_empty">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" To="22" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=IsFocused}" Value="False"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox_Test,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource StringEpmtyConverter}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>                                                    
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupBox.Style>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Test" Text="{Binding textTest}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <TextBox Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**StringEpmtyConverter.cs Converter:**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class StringEpmtyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope i was clear,
Thanks for help.

Comment: What are you currently trying and what is specifically going wrong?

Comment: I have no idea how to make the animation i want to achieve. From textbox hint text towards a groupbox header.

Comment: If i wasn't knew the knowledge i wasn't post here. I familiar with storyboard, triggers, data triggers, styles etc.. I post here because I searched and looking for some Instruction but couldn't found any to achieve what I'm looking for. I can write hint text inside the textbox, but when it focused how can i make the animation (like the picture).

Comment: if that is the case then please update your question with what you are currently trying so that we have a better idea as to where you are and how to help.

Comment: If you're familiar with storyboards etc., one idea that springs to mind is to have a rendertransform in your header template which uses a TranslateTransform to offset the header content on top of the upper left corner of the content area of the groupbox. When the content gains focus, animate the TranslateTransform from X=Whatever/Y=Whatever to X=0/Y=0. And vice versa. To enable the user to click on the text box, set IsHitTestVisible="False" on the header content.

Comment: One question for this idea, if i'm doing TranslateTransform X/Y with specific number that I have defined that's won't be dynamic from each textbox to another I think. (For example: textbox with height 100 and one with 200 the result would be different i think). Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: @Yuval In terms of UX or visual design, I would want the hint text to be in the upper left corner of the textbox, regardless of the size of the textbox. But to center it, I would be writing this whole thing as a subclass of GroupBox. When the content is rendered (OnApplyTemplate() or OnLoaded(), I think), I'd be calculating anything that needed to be calculated in C#, and exposing it via readonly dependency properties of the GroupBox subclass. The XAML could then bind to those as needed.

Comment: A less fancy option would be to write a [multi-value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) that you bind to the control's Content.ActualWidth and the control's header's ActualWidth (or the two ActualHeights), and have that do the necessary arithmetic for centering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, ill try that. Ill update soon as i have answer or question :)

Comment: @Yuval Groovy. Remember to @ me in your comments, or I won't get a notification

Comment: Hey, i update my code and have some question. Hope u can help me with that :) @EdPlunkett